# Gracefully remove html content that is outside of div

Tags: javascript, dom, html, google-translate

I'm using the google translation API that inserts some content into my page (a dropdown box) and some of the content is outside of any div or other element, but I want to remove it.

```
<div class="skiptranslate goog-te-gadget" style="">   
 <div id=":0.targetLanguage">
  <select class="goog-te-combo">
  </select>
 </div>
 Powered by   // want to remove this
```

I attempted doing so by reassigning the innerHTML of the containing div,

```
     var body = document.getElementById("container");
     body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML.replace("Powered by", " ");
```

But this seems to reset / break some other features of the API that I need to keep intact.

Is there a more graceful way of doing this?

**EDIT** - Regarding terms of service, if this isn't allowed, does anyone know of an open source API I can alternatively use?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't that violate the terms of service?

Comment: I'm not sure. This is more of a gadget then the full API, which may be different. Any specific documentation you know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Google Translate API v1 documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/reference.html):

> **Warning!** This API requires displaying attribution near any API input
>   boxes and the display of results, indicating that it is "Powered by
>   Google". If you choose not to use .getBranding(), you are obligated to
>   provide this branding yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove such thing I'm sure that you will infringing the Licence Agreement, and their for commit fraud.

Remember that the **[Google Translate API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html)** is deprecated in favor to a paid service.

The best way is to forget about Google Translator Service interely if you want the free version as they state [they will close](http://blog.gts-translation.com/2011/05/30/why-larry-page-killed-google-translate-api-and-other-assorted-thoughts/) it this year and use other Free Service, for example the [**Bing** Service](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/widget/).

Comment: I read through the terms but its not entirely clear to me. Do you know where it explicitly states so? What I am using is more or less just a dropdown to translate everything on the page (which is a free API)...whether that is being shut down on Dec 11th this year I'm not sure. Theres also this line: Content Returned from the API. You may store and modify content returned from the API if you abide by these terms.

Comment: Google says it will shutdown the service in favor of the v2. I never read anything that will state the reverse. You can easily use [Bing Service](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/widget/) for the same, that's what we are doing.

Answer (score 1):

In looking around for some information on the matter, I came up with the following :

Why don't you just shrink the 'extra' stuff to make it less intrusive on your site but still more legible than fine print at the bottom of most contracts. Thus you should stay compliant with the service's terms and not give up too much real estate on your page.

Here's the bit of CSS magic which should do the trick on most browsers :

...

```
/* shrinks the entire contents of the GoogleTranslate main div to 70%, still readable */
#google_translate_element {
  zoom: .7;
  -moz-transform: scale(.7); /* FireFox understands this */
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}

/* within that, further shrink 'provided by' text, which affects the math elsewhere ... */
#google_translate_element div {
  font-size: 25%;
}

/* on hover of the select (drop down), make it a bit bigger, don't forget it was shrunk */
#.0.targetLanguage select:hover {
  font-size: 2250%; /* don't ask, it worked in Chrome & Safari, IE 8 (!) seemed ok too */ 
}
```

...

I did a quick test using 'latest' Chrome, Safari, FireFox and MSie8, of all things, and the following to get the Google Translate displayed on a page :

...

```
<script>
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({
      pageLanguage: 'en',
      gaTrack: true,
      gaId: 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x',
      layout: google.translateElement.InLineLayout.HORIZONTAL
    }, 'google_translate_element');
  }
</script>

<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
</script>
```

...

Just noticed that FireFox, on Windows, is not doing the drop-down list.  But it has problem without the CSS trickery above (!!)

Play with the numbers, and your fav browsers to tweak to your needs.

I wanted to split the horizontal into two lines to make it more compact still.  That might need some JavaScript or otherwise to parse and sneak in a 
 just at the right spot ??  Maybe use similar to above to modify one of the other layouts supplied by Google.  As long as the logo is there, we should be ok ... right ?

Have fun !